# react native passing data from parent to child modal

Tags: react-native, state, react-native-flatlist, react-props

I have a FlatList rendered along with a ListItem so that onPress of a  specific row I can get that data inside my  ListTrips component. As shown below in my console.warn It will print the data of the selected item.

**Component A**

```
 import Component B from ...
 ....
  toggleModalConfirmTrip = item => {
console.warn(item);
// this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectedTrip', { item });

if (this.ModalConfirmTrip) {
  this.ModalConfirmTrip.toggleModal();
}
};


 <ListItem
 onPress={() => this.toggleModalConfirmTrip(item)}
 ....
```

Yet inside my ModalConfirmTrip.js I am unable to access the item. My question is how can I access it inside Component B?
I have tried playing around with props and state but cannot seem to get it right.

**Component B**

```
export default class ModalConfirmTrip extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  locationFrom: '',
  locatonTo: '',
  isVisible: false,
  id: null,
 };
}

toggleModal = () => {
this.setState({ isVisible: !this.state.isVisible });
 };

// API Call to update trip to active



render() {
const { isVisible, item } = this.state;

console.warn('Modal', this.state);
console.warn(this.props);

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Modal
      onBackdropPress={() => {
        this.toggleModal();
      }}
      isVisible={isVisible}
      hideModalContentWhileAnimating
    >
      <View style={styles.modalViewContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{this.state.item}</Text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

So you have to pass item as a prop in Component A

```
    <ModalConfirmTrip
      ref={ref => {
        this.ModalConfirmTrip = ref;
      }}
      item={this.state.item}
    />
```

Also to note you cannot pass an object of an array so I just passed the id of the trip. Hope this helps someone.